# url prefix in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, url-mapping

I use region separation on my site, the user can choose their current city. And I need to add the city code to the url, something like:

```
http://foo.bar/{city_prefix}/path?query
```

The city prefixes aren't static, they are stored in a DB. I need to add them to *any* url of the site.

Are there any route configs that can do this? Need any suggests how to realise it dynamically?

Comment: Have you looked at [*segment* routing configuration](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment)? This, with perhaps a listener attached to the  'route' event to validate the city is in the db would work. It would be easier to answer if you update your question to show what you have tried already.

Comment: Do u mean to use something like '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+' mask and listen for the route event when it checks the mask? How to attach to it?
Now I set city onBootstrap, but I dont know how to access the route building event to check city in url

Comment: Can't you just pass the city to the params of the url helper ? You could have a default value in your segment route and get the city from the session in order to pass it to the view helper url so that the view helper generate the url with the right city. As AlexP said, segment routing is what I would use